# text in bottomNavigationBar is not appeared !!! flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm new with flutter I just do my first app. So, Please forgive me if my question is not clear.

I'm now working on bottom navigation bar. I made it with icon and text but the icon and text for the first one only is appeared. the other only icons. How can I make all appeared?

Here is the code

```
bottomNavigationBar:  BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الرئيسية",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )
        ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.business, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "مرسال بيزنيس",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.local_activity, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "أنشطة مرسال",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "تبرع",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.help, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الأسئلة الشائعة",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            ))
      ],
        onTap: (currentIndex){
          _currentIndex  = currentIndex;
          if(_currentIndex==0)
            Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>new HomePage()));
          else if(_currentIndex==1)
            Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>new business()));
          else if(_currentIndex==2)
            Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>new activity()));
          else if(_currentIndex==3)
            Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>new donate()));
          else if(_currentIndex==4)
            Navigator.push(context,new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>new faq()));

        },
      ),
```

And that is the result:

[image]

Another question: how can I make the active item with different color?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to define a type fixed for your BottomNavigationBar

```
 bottomNavigationBar:  BottomNavigationBar(
    type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
    selectedItemColor: Colors.red,
    unselectedItemColor: Colors.black45,
    currentIndex: 4,


    items: [
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.home,/*color: Colors.black45*/),
          title: new Text(
            "الرئيسية",
            //style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          ),
      ),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.business, /*color: Colors.black45*/),
          title: new Text(
            "مرسال بيزنيس",
            //style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          )),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.local_activity, /*color: Colors.black45*/),
          title: new Text(
            "أنشطة مرسال",
           // style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          )),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite_border, /*color: Colors.black45*/),
          title: new Text(
            "تبرع",
            //style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          )),
      BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: new Icon(Icons.help, /*color:  Colors.black45 */),
          title: new Text(
            "الأسئلة الشائعة",
            //style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
          ))
    ],

  ),
```

Comment: Thank you very much it worked (Y) ... But How can I make the active item with different color ??

Comment: you need to remove the fixed color styles you are imposing to the NavigationBar and use selected item color . please check the edited code بالتوفيق

Answer (score 3):

Simply define a type for bottom navigation bar and you will see the text.

```
  type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
```

Tip :And now title is very much deprecated so use label property instead of title.

```
 BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: Icon(Icons.attach_email),
          label: "Emails",
          backgroundColor: Colors.yellow.shade900),
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do some refactoring to your code to make it more readable and clean instead of using nested if's and else you can just do like the above code, make sure that the void function inside the class and outside the Widget Build Function to avoid any errors.

```
 void onTabTapped(int index) {
    setState(() {
      _currentIndex = index;
    });
  }

bottomNavigationBar:  BottomNavigationBar(
        items: [
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.home, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الرئيسية",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )
        ),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.business, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "مرسال بيزنيس",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.local_activity, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "أنشطة مرسال",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.favorite_border, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "تبرع",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            )),
         BottomNavigationBarItem(
            icon: new Icon(Icons.help, color: Colors.black45),
            title: new Text(
              "الأسئلة الشائعة",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black45),
            ))
      ],
        onTap:onTabTapped,
      ),
```